# SWIFT:Trying to change start number to match updated number every time code is ran

Tags: swift

Newbie here, I'm trying to change the value of startNumber to the value of updatedNumber every time the code is ran. so it would start at 10 then depending on number removed eventually get to zero. right now it just starts over back at 10 every time. any help here would be much appreicated.

```
var startNumber = 10
var numberRemoved = 1
var updatedNumber = startNumber - numberRemoved

if (startNumber - numberRemoved == startNumber) {

    print("you still have \(startNumber) left")
    
} else if (startNumber - numberRemoved < startNumber) {

    print("your new total is \(updatedNumber)")
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the docs for `UserDefaults` and/or `@AppStorage` to store and make available your `startNumber` when you start your App again.
Looking at your (meaningless) code, such as: `if (startNumber - numberRemoved == startNumber) ...`
 I recommend you start reading about Swift and programming in general. There are many
 good tutorials on the net.

Comment: Thanks for your (meaningful) answer. Literally brand new at this, currently going through online course. Ill make sure next time I ask a question its not seeping with obvious inexperince.